# How can I use js (or moment.js) to check if a date is past the current date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

So now I'm just trying to get the dates from the para class to print to the console. Jquery and moment are both working fine. Right now this logs nothing to the console. I need to see if the current date is x days after any of the dates with a class of para. At this point I would be happy with just logging the class dates to the console.

js

```
        const dates = $('.para');

        dates.each((i, elem) => {
         let parts = $(elem).text().split('/');
           let dt = new Date(parts[2] ,parts[1], parts[0]).getTime();
           let diff = Math.floor((dt - new Date().getTime()) / (86400 * 
         1000));
       console.log('date:', $(elem).text(), 'days diff vs today:', diff);
      });
```

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title></title>
     <script src="moment.js"></script>

       <script 
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/
  ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
   3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
   </script>
   <script src="forrealz.js"></script>



        </head>
      <body>

     <p class="para">
    11/18/2021
      </p>
    <p class="para">
  09/12/1999
     </p>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Update: Tried this in code pen instead of chrome and it works but the math is wrong.
 "date:" "
      09/18/2018
    " "days diff vs today:" 284
"date:" "
      09/12/1999
    " "days diff vs today:" -6837

Comment: It'll be helpful to see your html code as well

Comment: `i < element.length;` looks like a potential typo.  Did you mean to use $element there?

Comment: However, the loop there doesn't really make sense, since the element will only ever be one `p` element at a time

Comment: Additionally, `formatted` is a string. I'd imagine `formatted[i]` is going to output just one character.

Comment: For testing I just have <p class="para">
      23/05/2021
    </p>
    <p class="para">
      19/12/1999
    </p>

Comment: The real table is on sharepoint so once I get this working i'll alter it and js link to the table.

Comment: The number of `p` is not the issue here.  We've listed a few things that look like logical errors that you need to investigate.  You can check/verify things by either debugging with `debugger;` statements or you can throw some `console.log(...thing...)` in the code to see what value things have

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

The following gets the date text from your html, parses it into month, day, and year, and then converts it to a js date object to be compared to the current date. The date difference is converted from milliseconds to days for output.

```js
const dates = $('.para');
dates.each((i, elem) => {
  const [m, d, y] = $(elem).text().split('/');
  const dt = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
  const diff = Math.floor((dt - new Date()) / (86400 * 1000));
  console.log('date:', $(elem).text(), 'days diff vs today:', diff);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="para">05/23/2021</p>
<p class="para">12/19/1999</p>
```

ORIGINAL (before edits that removed moment.js code and added the html to the question):

You can get the date difference in days using vanilla js by parsing the date text from your html and converting to js date objects so you can do a little math to convert the difference in milliseconds to days (rounded to whole days in the example below).

The `dates` array in the example below is a placeholder for the collection of date elements you would select from your html (wasn't sure from your question / comments if you are working with a `table` or with `p` elements). Working snippet to illustrate:

```js
const dates = ['05/23/2021', '12/19/1999'];
for (const date of dates) {
  const [m, d, y] = date.split('/');
  const dt = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
  const diff = Math.floor((dt - new Date()) / (86400 * 1000));
  console.log('date:', date, 'days diff vs today:', diff);
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. Instead of the dates being written directly in a var I need one to be the current time and the other to be an array of all the data stored in the para class.

Comment: Ah I misread that. So I just need the dates in the array to come from the para class.

Comment: @emilyk that is correct. You could do something like `document.querySelectorAll('.para')` to get all your dates in a collection and then access the `textContent` property of each one in the loop to split into date parts, etc. Will add an example to the answer to be clear.

Comment: Weird. It works perfectly when I run the code snippet but when I try it in my text editor and preview in chrome nothing is logged to the console. Not even an error.

Comment: All I have are moment and jquery. Will try what you said though.

Comment: Still can't get it to work but I really appreciate all of your help :)

Comment: Where did these numbers come from?   (86400 * 1000)

Comment: @emilyk that is the shorthand I typically use for converting milliseconds to days: 1000 milliseconds per second * 86,400 seconds per day (60 seconds per minute * 60 minutes per hour * 24 hours per day).

Comment: Ok thanks. The day diff printed to the console is off by hundreds of days. Is there and alt formula I could use?

Comment: @emilyk there was an error in setting the right month because I neglected to adjust the month value to an index value (js months are indexed 0 - 11) - edited the answer to correct the issue. But this should only have affected the calc by roughly 30 days. Can you give an example of the dates you are calculating and the results?

Comment: 09/12/2018 -> "date:" "
      09/12/2018
    " "days diff vs today:" 71

Comment: 08/23/2018 -> "date:" "
      08/23/2018
    " "days diff vs today:" 405

Comment: @emilyk I see now... your original post did not include any dates, so I used the format of the dates in the comment you posted to parse the input dates (which was dd/mm/yyyy). I see now that you have edited the question with dates in  mm/dd/yyyy format, which is why you are getting crazy results. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @emilyk the important thing is that you understand the order of parameters in `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)` so that when you parse the date text, you pass the matching date parts to the correct function parameter.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that I had changed to format. This works perfectly now! Thank you soooo much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Momentjs `diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) is the key function here:

```
var dayDifference = 10;

var d = new Date();
var momentDate = moment(d);

$('p.para').each(function (index, element) {
    var date = moment($(this).text().trim(), 'M/D/YYYY');
    if (momentDate.diff(date, 'days') < dayDifference) {
        // display alert
    }
}
```

This can be applied to html example you provided:

```
<p class="para"> 23/05/2021 </p>
<p class="para"> 19/12/1999 </p>
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to get an alert or console log working

Comment: Try to console.log(momentDate.diff(date, 'days')) inside the loop and see if it actually counting day difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment.diff` function. Follow these [docs for moment difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), for better understanding.

Sample JS:

```
let d = moment(inputDate, 'M/D/YYYY');

if ( d.isValid() ) {
    let differenceInDays = moment().diff(d, 'days', true);  // moment() gives current date time.

    if (differenceInDays > 0) {
        console.log("Past current Date");
    }

}
```